# SQL: Ambigious column resolution without change in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL Query :

```
SELECT call_type FROM INCOMING_CALLS, LIVE_CALLS 

WHERE LIVE_CALLS.status='INCALL' and INCOMING_CALLS.callerid = LIVE_CALLS.callerid

AND pbl_id in ('111','190','121','111','-','111','121','303','6730','-');
```

Both the tables, LIVE_CALLS and INCOMING_CALLS have the column pbl_id. Which obviously results into the following error :

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'pbl_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

I understand that it's very simple to solve this problem by changing

```
pbl_id in (
```

to

```
INCOMING_CALLS.pbl_id in (
```

and

```
INCOMING_CALLS.pbl_id in (
```

But I can not do that as the below part is dynamically dynamically build and I do not have control over it.

```
AND pbl_id in ('111','190','121','111','-','111','121','303','6730','-');
```

I need to match the pbl_id of both tables. Any hints how can I achieve that?

Comment: How is that dynamical query part built?

Comment: A method returning a variable with that string. Does it matter by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub-query:

```
select call_type
from INCOMING_CALLS ic
inner join (select distinct callerid from LIVE_CALLS
            where LIVE_CALLS.status='INCALL') lc
    on ic.callerid = lc.callerid
where 1 = 1
AND pbl_id in ('111','190','121','111','-','111','121','303','6730','-');
```

See it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60238/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you add the statement:

```
INCOMING_CALLS.pbl_id = LIVE_CALLS.pbl_id
```

and then compare one of the two with the in statement

```
AND INCOMING_CALLS.pbl_id in ('111','190','121','111','-','111','121','303','6730','-');
```

On second thought, why don't you just join the tables?

```
SELECT call_type FROM INCOMING_CALLS
LEFT JOIN LIVE_CALLS ON LIVE_CALLS.pbl_id = INCOMING_CALLS.pbl_id
WHERE LIVE_CALLS.status='INCALL' and INCOMING_CALLS.callerid = LIVE_CALLS.callerid
AND pbl_id in ('111','190','121','111','-','111','121','303','6730','-');
```

Comment: AND INCOMING_CALLS.pbl_id in ('111','190','121','111','-','111','121','303','6730','-');

I cant prepend INCOMING_CALLS tp pbl_id as I do not have control over it, as mentioned in the question. Thanks!

Comment: You do not have control over it... I wonder how that works out in code.

Comment: I just read your other comment, why not use a str_replace on the pbl_id and add the prefix for the table?

Comment: That works out in code when you are collaborating in a team. Thanks for your help. Joining the table is the solutions.